# Limiting Azure Functions Rate of Service Bus Message Intake

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, message-queue, azureservicebus

Suppose we have the following scenario:

- Service Bus Queue with 10,000 messages
- Azure Functions (on Consumption plan) with function set up as a trigger for the SB Queue
- An external (out of our control) system which **fails past a certain request rate**

If I queue those 10k messages as fast as I can, the external system is not able to handle the concurrent load. I don't know how many function instances or app service instances ("*scale out*") Azure runs at the same time to process these messages.

Here is a code sample of what my function definition looks like:

```cs
public class MyQueueProcessor
{
    private IMyDependency MyDependency { get; }

    public MyQueueProcessor(IMyDependency myDependency)
    {
        MyDependency = myDependency;
    }

    [FunctionName(nameof(MyQueueProcessor))]
    public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("my-queue-name", Connection = "MyQueueConnection")] string item, ILogger log)
    {
        var req = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyQueueRequest>(item);

        log.LogInformation($"Beginning processing of " + req);

        // Valudate req
        // Call external service REST API
        await MyDependency.CallService(req, new { otherParameters = true });

        log.LogInformation($"Finished processing of " + req);
    }
}
```

I am not able to process all 10k messages with a single function because the external service call takes a number of seconds to complete (5-10s), and processing all of these messages with one function call would exceed the 10min maximum for function calls.

How can I limit the number of concurrent functions running that are consuming the messages from my queue?

Comment: Maybe durable functions is what you need: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp#async-http

Comment: I can see some setting for v1 host.json to control concurrent request https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus (don't see for v2)

Comment: This question and  the answer bellow, reveals just some of the operational problems , and cognitive overhead, imposed by Azure Functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can now limit the number of *instances* with **"Enforce Scale Out Limit"** in the Azure Portal under the **"Scale out"** menu on your Azure Function App.
When it is turned off the limit will default to 200 instances on a consumption plan.

Note that when you are using the Service Bus binding each instance can also receive and process messages concurrently. You can limit this by setting `maxConcurrentCalls` in `host.json`. The default value is 16.

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
        "autoComplete": true,
        "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:05:00",
        "maxConcurrentCalls": 16
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The maximum number of messages being processed concurrently will then be the number of instances multiplied by `maxConcurrentCalls`.

Comment: Keep in mind that this will affect all ServiceBusTriggered functions in the app. If you are trying to limit concurrency / throttle a specific function and not others, this will not be a valid solution.